# How to Create Hyperlink in Workbook Cell to Hard Drive File using a Userform Textbox and Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Userform that uses textboxes as a source to add data onto a worksheet.
The way it does so is simple: specified cells equal textbox value.

One of my columns is for photo links that go to a folder on my computer. This is where I am stuck, as I can add the filepath to the cell from my textbox, but it is not highlighted blue and underlined(not hyperlinked). That is something I want to be automated.

Thank you for your time guys, this team is literally the best I have found online!

Note: As you will see in my code, my Folder path and file format will always be the same, with the textbox value making all the difference; "filepath" & userform.textbox.value & ".jpg". I like it this way for some good reasons, and changing it is not really an option I have. Suggestions and education however are sought after!

Code:

```
    With ws
      '.Unprotect Password:="password"
      .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = DRAFT1.PART2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = DRAFT1.LOC2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = DRAFT1.DESC2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 5).Value = DRAFT1.QTY2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 8).Value = DRAFT1.DATE2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 9).Value = DRAFT1.POS2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 10).Value = DRAFT1.TYPE2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 11).Value = DRAFT1.COLOR2.Value
      .Cells(iRow, 12).Value = DRAFT1.FEATURES2.Value

      'this is where I am having trouble
      .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = "C:\User\ttech\Desktop\EXCEL\PHOTOS\" & DRAFT1.PHOTO2.Value & ".jpg"
      'I tried ActiveSheets.Hyperlink.Add(filepath...) 
      'And (filepath...).hyperlinks

      .Cells(iRow, 14).Value = DRAFT1.OTHERNAMES2.Value
    '  .Protect Password:="password"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.hyperlinks.add Anchor:= .Cells(iRow, 13), Address:= "C:\User\ttech\Desktop\EXCEL\PHOTOS\" & DRAFT1.PHOTO2.Value & ".jpg", TextToDisplay:= "C:\User\ttech\Desktop\EXCEL\PHOTOS\" & DRAFT1.PHOTO2.Value & ".jpg"
```

Not sure how you tried the hyperlinks add but it should work as above

You don't need the active sheet if its contained within your with

Comment: I like the way it looks. When I tried it, it said "Expected: end of statement" and highlighted the Anchor part of the script. Which I think is a little strange myself

Comment: If it helps, iRow is Dimmed as Long, don't know if that matters or not. Also, the sub is a Private Sub contained within a "Click" kind of macro.

Comment: Could just be spacing. I've amended my answer. Let me know if that works

Comment: Hmm...same thing. Is there any kind of setting I might have that's affecting the way this code works?

Comment: It works perfectly for me (With adjusted variables of course) have you got an example of what `DRAFT1.PHOTO2.Value` would be

Comment: It would be a number such as 0430451012, or a number with dashes in it or a number with letters in it. So all-in-all it would equal C:\user\ttech\Desktop\Excel\Photos\0430451012.jpg.
Or something similar to that.

Comment: Hmm this error is to do with the syntax but i'm not seeing what is wrong. Can you comment back exactly how you have this in your code?

Comment: You know, your code is perfect. *I* made the mistake of leaving the .Cells(iRow, 13).Value = code in place. I just overwrote the entire string of code with the one you provided, and it works perfectly. *facepalm*

Comment: Thank you a ton for your help, I have been (embarrasingly) well-educated today!

Comment: Haha no problem. I swear the easiest, most obvious, mistakes are the hardest to see!